# Writing Verticles that performs CRUD Operations on a file

Tags: vert.x

I'm new to Vert.x and trying I am trying to implement a small REST API that stores its data in JSON files on the local file system.

So far I managed to implement the REST API since Vertx is very well documented on that part.

What I'm currently looking for are examples how to build data access objects in Vert.x. How can I implement a Verticle that can perform crud operations on a text file containing JSON?

Can you provide me any examples? Any hints?

**UPDATE 1:**

By CRUD operations on a file I'm thinking of the following. Imagine there is a REST resource called `Records` exposed on the the path `/api/v1/user/:userid/records/`.

In my verticle that starts my HTTP server I have the following routes.

```
router.get('/api/user/:userid/records').handler(this.&handleGetRecords)
router.post('/api/user/:userid/records').handler(this.&handleNewRecord)
```

The handler methods `handleGetRecords` and `handleNewRecord` are sending a message using the Vertx event bus.

```
request.bodyHandler({ b ->

   def userid = request.getParam('userid')

   logger.info "Reading record for user {}", userid
            vertx.eventBus().send(GET_TIME_ENTRIES.name(), "read time records", [headers: [userId: userid]], { reply ->

   // This handler will be called for every request
   def response = routingContext.response()

   if (reply.succeeded()) {
      response.putHeader("content-type", "text/json")
      // Write to the response and end it
                    response.end(reply.result().body())
   } else {

      logger.warn("Reply failed {}", reply.failed())
      response.statusCode = 500
      response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")

      response.end('That did not work out well')
   }
  })
})
```

Then there is another verticle that consumes these messages `GET_TIME_ENTRIES` or `CREATE_TIME_ENTRY`. I think of this consumer verticle as a Data Access Object for `Records`. This verticle can read a file of the given `:userid` that contains all user records. The verticle is able to

- add a record
- read all records
- read a specific record
- update a record
- delete a or all records

Here is the example of reading all records.

```
vertx.eventBus().consumer(GET_TIME_ENTRIES.name(), { message ->

    String userId = message.headers().get('userId')
    String absPath = "${this.source}/${userId}.json" as String

    vertx.fileSystem().readFile(absPath, { result ->

        if (result.succeeded()) {
            logger.info("About to read from user file {}", absPath)
            def jsonObject = new JsonObject(result.result().toString())
            message.reply(jsonObject.getJsonArray('records').toString())
        } else {
            logger.warn("User file {} does not exist", absPath)
            message.fail(404, "user ${userId} does not exist")
        }
    })
})
```

What I trying to achieve is to read the file like I did above and deserialise the JSON into a POJO (e.g. a `List<Records>`). This seems much more convenient that working with `JsonObject` of Vertx. I don't want to manipulate the JsonObject instance.

Comment: What do you mean by CRUD Operations on a file? Vert.x has a Filesystem API for async file operations, if that's what you're looking for http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_using_the_file_system_with_vert_x

Comment: @tsegismont thanks for your feedback. I tried to be more precise. Please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your approach using EventBus is fine, in my opinion. It may be a bit slower, because EventBus will serialize/deserialize your objects, but it gives you a very good decoupling.

Example of another approach you can see here:
https://github.com/aesteve/vertx-feeds/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/examples/feeds/dao/RedisDAO.java

Note how every method receives handler as its last argument:

```
public void getMaxDate(String feedHash, Handler<Date> handler) {
```

More coupled, but also more efficient.

And for a more classic and straightforward approach, you can see the official examples:

https://github.com/aokolnychyi/vertx-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/aokolnychyi/vertx/example/dao/MongoDbTodoDaoImpl.java

You can see that here DAO is pretty much synchronous, but since the handlers are still async, it's fine anyway.

Comment: I chose the eventBus in order to be able to run the solution in clustered mode. But of course you are right about the serialisation/deserialisation overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following link will help you out and this is a good example of Vertx crud operations.

[Vertx student crud operations using hikari](https://github.com/saranglohar/vertx-crud-operations-demo)